# Wordpress add_theme_support( 'custom-header' ) does not add option to dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a new theme from scratch, based off the Toolbox theme. My installation of WP is straight out of the box. I added `add_theme_support('custom-header');` to my functions.php file, but the "header" options screen does not appear in the dashboard. I can see it if I visit the site, in the toolbar at the top, but not in the dashboard. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not implemented yet - that won't work until 4.3 is released, and until then, you have to use

```
add_custom_image_header()
```